# Variable Address Doesn't Change Each Runtime with Code:Blocks on Windows

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Each time I run below code in Linux it prints a different address (this is the normal thing I guess),
But when I run it with Code:Blocks using gcc on Windows, It ALWAYS print the same address, Why is that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n = 1;
    printf("%p",&n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, different operation systems use various measures to prevent malware from doing their work. This might be an effect of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)... But I might be wrong.

Comment: @thebusybee so this because of the OS, not a "special environment" Code:Block is making for me ?

Comment: What gcc/mingw version? 32 bit? 64 bit? Which Windows version?

Comment: Well, probably. Linker options might change things and flags that control how the OS initiates the executable.

Comment: @Lundin gcc 8.1.0 64 bit Windows10

Comment: The MS linker has a `/DYNAMICBASE` option to enable address randomization. Windows otherwise doesn't do that, as some older programs wouldn't work properly.